# Understanding addEventListener callbacks from api?

Tags: javascript, jitsi-meet

I'm just trying to wrap my head around an event listener in Jitsi Meet API, I haven't run across something like this and I'm sure its the same concept in alot of api's - I'm not sure on approach.

Basically in the jitsi meet api you can use api.addEventListener(audioMuteStatusChanged, listener); to set up an event listener if mute is toggled. Basically, true if muted, false if not. I'm trying to get a value of if it to see when it's muted, or when it isn't muted.

It says "The listener parameter is a Function object with one argument that will be notified when the event occurs with data related to the event."

So how do I get the true false value when something is changed?

```
const result = api.addEventListener(audioMuteStatusChanged, return isitmuted);
```

**Edit:** Tried it with:

```
 if (audioChatApi) {
  audioChatApi.addEventListener(audioMuteStatusChanged, function(listener) {
   if (listener){
     console.log("True " + listener);
   } else {
     console.log("False");
   };
 });
 };
```

and didn't solve it, I think the event isn't for this task

Comment: How is that even related @deceze

Comment: It very much is. I've added a bunch of duplicates about callbacks. Read them to get familiar with the concept.

Comment: @RobStark — You're trying to put a `return` statement somewhere that a function is expected. You need to put a function there and you can't return from it (at least not to `result`).

Comment: It's the same principle, you can't. You have to trigger whatever has to happen to the true/false value inside the event handler.

Comment: In a simple nutshell: the *event* `audioMuteStatusChanged` will happen ***sometime later***, possibly multiple times, unpredictably. It makes no sense to want to return anything from it. No, you need to bind a `function` to that event so you can *do* something when that event happens. You don't `return` anything then, you *do* something then.

Comment: *"and didn't solve it, I think the event isn't for this task"* – What does that mean? What did it do, what didn't it do, what did you want it to do?

Comment: @deceze I tried to console.log it (made an edit above) and it wouldn't do anything - I'm guessing the eventlistener is not for this purpose. This is logged by default by jitsy whenever I mute the chat, it shows:

[modules/API/API.js] <Object.toggle-audio>:  Audio toggle: API command received

Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/JitsiLocalTrack.js] <r>:  Mute LocalTrack[1,audio]: true

Which would flip true and false accordingly, i thought this would be able to grab that true false value somehow

Comment: It probably should. Though what is `audioMuteStatusChanged` exactly? It should be the name of an event, not a variable (unless that variable holds the name of the event, but that's odd). It should be something like `audioChatApi.addEventListener('audioMuteStatusChanged', function ...)`.

Comment: @deceze according to https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md it says "audioMuteStatusChanged - event notifications about audio mute status changes."

I just got it working by using something else on same list, api.isAudioMuted().then(function(muted) {

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be something like the following?

```
const result = api.addEventListener(audioMuteStatusChanged, function(isMuted) {
  if (isMuted){
    //some code here
  } else {
    //some code here
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it with:

  if (audioChatApi) {
    audioChatApi.addEventListener(audioMuteStatusChanged, function(listener) {
      if (listener){
        console.log("True " + listener);
      } else {
        console.log("False");
      };
    });
  };

and looks like the event is just not for this job